# error: ‘outList’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a program for my intro to C class and keep getting some warnings when I try to compile with gcc.

Here is my code:

```
char **outList;
*outList = strdup(cloudDevice);
printf("this is device XML message: %s",*outList);
```

Any ideas why? Thank you

Comment: char **outList;
    *outList = strdup(cloudDevice);
     printf("this is device XML message: %s",*outList);

Answer (score 3):

It's complaining because you're using an uninitialized pointer, you reference `outList` before he pointes anywhere

why do you use `char **` and not `char *` ?

```
char *outList;

outList = strdup(cloudDevice);
printf("this is device XML message: %s", outList);
```

Comment: this a test for a function so i need to use char**

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I had to use `malloc`.

```
char **outList = malloc(sizeof (char **) * 256) ;  
outList = strdup(cloudDevice);
printf("this is device XML message: %s",*outList);
```

Comment: No you're not. (1) In all logic you need `sizeof(char*)` (allocate some `char*`, return a pointer to them). (2) Why the `256` ? (3) On your second line, you need to assign to `*outList`. Your compiler should scream about that one.